# $\mathbb{Q}$ with the metric $d(p,q) = |p-q|$

Tags: general-topology

> Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ ,the set of rational  number , with  metric $d(p,q) = |p-q|$.then  which of the following statement is true ?
>
> $a)$$\{q \in \mathbb{Q} : 2< q^2 < 3 \}$ is closed
>
> $b)$ $\{ q \in  \mathbb{Q} : 2  \le q^2 \le 4\}$ is compact
>
> $c)$ $\{ q\in \mathbb{Q} : 2 \le  q^2  \le 4 \}$ is closed

---

My attempt  : I think option $b)$ and option $c)$ is correct by  Heine Boral  theorem : closed + bounded = compact

Is this True ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hints.**
>
> (a) **True**. First try to check whether the set $\{q \in \Bbb{Q}|\sqrt 2< q< \sqrt 3\}$ is closed or not. Well, it is closed in $\Bbb{Q}$, w.r.to the subspace topology from $\Bbb{R}$. Since see that, $\{q \in \Bbb{Q}|\sqrt 2< q< \sqrt 3\}=[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]\cap \Bbb{Q}$ where $[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$.
>
> (b) **False**. See that there is a sequence in this set that converges to $\sqrt 2$, which is not in the set (because of density property of $\Bbb{Q}$ in that closed interval). So, the set is not even **Sequentially Compact**.
>
> (c) **True**. Same logic as in (a). Think about the set $[\sqrt 2, 2]\cap \Bbb{Q}$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

The Heine-Borel Theorem only applies to $\mathbb R$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is a different topological space, you cannot characterize the compact subspaces of $\mathbb Q$ using the same criteria. Instead, use the fact that a compact metric space must be complete. Or you could use the fact that every sequence in a compact set has a convergent subsequence. Can you find a sequence in the set in (b) that does not have a convergent subsequence?

For a set to be closed, its complement must be open. What do the complements of the sets in (a) and (c) look like? Are they open in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: im not getting    how can we find complement

Comment: For (a), the set is all the rational numbers whose square is between 2 and 3. The complement is all rational numbers whose square is less than 2 or greater than 3. Note that the square roots of 2 and 3 are not rational, so the complement of this set does not contain its endpoints.